# I can't send numerical values from a table using a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
Alter function calcular(@cajas int, @peso int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  set @cajas = (select cant_entr from entrega)
  set @peso = (select peso_entr from entrega)

  DECLARE @mercaderia int;
  SELECT @mercaderia = @cajas * @peso * 0.5

  RETURN @mercaderia;
END
go 

SELECT 
    dbo.calcular(cant_entr, peso_entr), matr_veh 
FROM
    entrega, vehiculo 
WHERE 
    matr_veh = 'PTK-0165'
```

it should returns more than one value from all the rows but I want all those rows to be added where all matching values have the car plate = PTK-0165.

THIS IS WHAT I AM BEING ASKED: Create a function that calculates the value (number of boxes * weight *0.5) of the transported merchandise from 'route sheet' where truck plates = 'PTK-0165'

Comment: sorry cannot understand what do you want and don't get why you are reseting the parameters [cajas] and [peso] with (random?) values from [entrega] table

Comment: You have so many issues in this code it is hard to know where to start. First is setting the variables in your function, they will always have the same value no matter parameters you pass in because your queries have no where clause. You shouldn't use a scalar function for this, it is just going to slow down everything. Last but not least, you have two tables separated by commas in the from clause. This generates a cross join.

Comment: variable '@mercaderia' is defined as INT. However you are using decimals in multiplication. Change the datatype of @mercaderia to decimal or numeric  with scale and precision.

Comment: @SeanLange Ill post the question that is asking me what to do

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: If this is homework you should ask your professor why they are teaching their students poor performing ways of writing sql.

Comment: @marc_s yes my teacher told us that but he wants us to use a function for now to see performance.

Comment: @BlindSteven92: not saying anything about the **function** (other than it won't perform well....) - what I say you **ought to avoid** is the `SELECT ... FROM  entrega, vehiculo  ...` style of joining two tables - use the **proper ANSI JOIN syntax** instead!

Comment: @marc_s ok, ill do that. Im new to this.

Answer (score 2):

I would drop the scalar function and put the calculation in your query. That scalar function is only going to make your query slower for no reason at all. And of course as coded that function is a disaster.

Not sure if you really want that cross join or if that should be an inner/outer join but this code should be close to what you want without all the extra hassle of a function.

```
SELECT e.cant_entr * e.peso_entr * .5 as calcular
    , matr_veh 
from entrega e
cross join vehiculo v
where v.matr_veh='PTK-0165'
```

---

--EDIT--

Since your professor is demanding a function and there is no mention about the type you should use an inline table valued function. This is easier to work with and has the added benefit of not destroying the performance of your query. Something along these lines.

```
create function calcular
(
    @cajas int
    , @peso int
) returns table as
    RETURN
    select @cajas * @peso * .5 as mercarderia

go

SELECT c.mercarderia
    , matr_veh 
from entrega e
cross join vehiculo v
cross apply calcular(e.cant_entr, e.peso_entr) c
where v.matr_veh='PTK-0165'
```

---

--FINAL EDIT--

Since your teacher wants you to see the performance difference then you should make this a scalar function. Here is how you would do that.

```
Alter function calcular(@cajas int, @peso int)
RETURNS decimal(7, 2)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @mercaderia decimal(7, 2);
  SELECT @mercaderia = @cajas * @peso * 0.5
  RETURN @mercaderia;
END
go
```

Comment: I posted the question, it will return more than one value from those car plates

Comment: The only advantage a function brings to this is by making it slower.

Comment: thank you. Its not really homework, he just wants us to see performance between joins and functions.